# Possible to Create "Stub" File for Undetectable Modules for PyLint?

Tags: python, subclass, pylint, cpython

My Python project is embedded and interpreted from a C++ application. This application also exposes certain classes/functions into a module called "Monsters" that the Python can import. So importing the "Slime" class from it would look like this: `from Monsters import Slime`

The issue is PyLint cannot detect this module due to the nature in which it is implemented. As a result, it generates errors such as: `Unable to import 'Monsters'`. These kinds of errors alone are not an issue since they could be suppressed without an issue.

However, the module contains classes that need to be extended in Python. These subclasses have access to their parent variables/functions that are built within the C++ implementation. Accessing them causes another error: `Instance of 'Child_Slime' has no 'x' member`. The "x" property is implemented in the parent class, but PyLint does not know about it.

This ability to check whether certain members within an object/class exist is a huge reason why I wanted to use PyLint to begin with, so I would prefer if I didn't have to completely suppress the warning all together. Is there any way to generate a [stub file similar to MyPy's](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#library-stubs-and-the-typeshed-repo) but for PyLint? If not, is there any alternative Python linters that would contain such a feature?